# Consistent factor values across multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a CSV file with four fields:

```
ID, choice1, choice2, choice3
```

The three choice fields are strings that represent categorical variables, where the domain is the same in each case.

I want to read this in using R and have these as factors, not strings, but using consistent level values across the columns. So 'foo' in choice1 columns has the same value as 'foo' in choice2 column, etc.

How do I do ensure that the categorical type is the same across all the choice columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you need the columns in as characters and convert them to a factor yourself:

```
data = read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
levels = with(data, unique(c(choice1, choice2, choice3)))
data = within(data, {
    choice1 = factor(choice1, levels),
    choice2 = factor(choice2, levels),
    choice3 = factor(choice3, levels),
})
```

`read.csv` has a `colClasses` parameter but that expects character class names, so it’s unfortunately not useful here.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it like this although not quite as elegantly; I used non-R tools to make set of unique values across all the columns as a file, then read that in and made the values factors (which you do much better in your second line), then did the conversion like you did.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution that allows you to precompute the "common factor" column indexes and avoid subsequent repetition of them (using my own randomish data):

```
system('cat data.csv');
## ID,choice1,choice2,choice3
## 1,A,B,E
## 2,A,C,D
## 3,B,B,A
## 4,B,D,E
raw <- read.csv('data.csv',stringsAsFactors=F);
fcols <- grep('^choice\\d$',names(raw));
levels <- unique(do.call(c,raw[,fcols,drop=F]));
dat <- data.frame(c(raw[,-fcols,drop=F],lapply(raw[,fcols,drop=F],factor,levels)));
dat;
##   ID choice1 choice2 choice3
## 1  1       A       B       E
## 2  2       A       C       D
## 3  3       B       B       A
## 4  4       B       D       E
lapply(dat,levels);
## $ID
## NULL
## 
## $choice1
## [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
## 
## $choice2
## [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
## 
## $choice3
## [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```